# OkHttp Async call returning JsonArray Null

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I declared a global JSONArray variable to return in okHttpCallback function but it returns null. I am getting data,But while returning it is null

```
JSONArray jsonArray; //Global in class

public JSONArray getJsonString(String link){

            okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        try {

                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else{
                        Log.d("ERROR", "onResponse: ERROR" + response.body().string());
                    }
                }
            });


       return jsonArray; // Null Here

    }
```

Comment: is ' jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());' having value ?

Comment: print the response in the logcat

Comment: @sree yes having value

Comment: @Swamy, It seems background tasks are still running and you return `jsonArray` which is null. Background tasks are not yet completed

Comment: @sree onResponse is a void method

Comment: @RakeshKumar what is the general way of return a data string or jsonArray using OkHttp

Comment: @Swamy 'getJsonString' function need to wait till onResponse get called. You are merging two thread.

Comment: @Swamy, Use `AsyncTask` or `RxJava` to perform a task on the background thread and as you get a result then do your functionality

Comment: why didn't you use `link` in your getJsonString function. And could you show to us your request?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the network call is taking place in another thread and you are returning `jsonArray` in main thread. You should return jsonArray only when you get response through okhttp. 
You should do as follows :-

```
public void getJsonResponse(String link){

            okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        try {

                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                            getJsonString(jsonArray);

                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else{
                        Log.d("ERROR", "onResponse: ERROR" + response.body().string());
                    }
                }
            });


    }

  // somewhere in class 

public JSONArray getJsonString(JSONArray jsonArr)
{
   return jsonArr;
}
```

Comment: Where do you returning JSONArray, the getJsonResponse is void

Comment: and are you sure your response is in json array format not an object format... ????